# cufon font replacement issue on iPad jquery scroll

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, cufon

I'm having the [same problem as this example here](http://ralf-schmitz.de/aktuell/).
When i use `Cufon` font replacement on a iPad or iPhone, there is a delay in the font to scroll inside its div. 
Everything seems to work fine on a desktop browser, but on mobiles the fonts "stick" and do not scroll smoothly.

Does anyone have a fix to this please?

Comment: Is this a new project? If so I would advice you to run away from cufon while you still can.

Comment: @PeeHaa is there a substitute for cufon that is more reliable?

Comment: Anything is better than cufon. I suggest you look into `@font-face`.

Comment: @PeeHaa can you give some info about font-face, will accept as an answer please

Comment: Here you can upload your font and it will give you the converted fonts and the CSS that you need: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator. And if you are trying to use it with fonts that aren't really allowed to be used on the web (I won't judge) you can use either one of these services: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6081152#6081152

Comment: changed to `@font-face` but now im having all sorts of problems with x-browser issues

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19446/discussion-between-t-q-and-peehaa)